# Custom theme not visible in Appearance

Tags: theme-development, themes

Wordpress initial install. Version `5.3`

> index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
   <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
 test
</body>
```

> style.css

```
/*
Theme Name: Gerboni
Theme URI: http://linards-berzins.co.uk/
Author: Linards Bērziņš
Author URI: http://linards-berzins.co.uk/
Description: Woocommerce theme for online shop
Version: 1.0
Text-domain: gerboni
License: GNU General Public License v2 or later
License URI: https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
Tags: e-commerce, blog, custom-menu, custom-logo, featured-images,footer-widgets, theme-options, translation-ready, right-sidebar, sticky-post, threaded-comments
*/
```

Theme Appearance dashboard:
[image]

Any advice appreciated.

Comment: Where do you put the files? Is it in `wp-content/themes/your-theme`?

Comment: Correct @SallyCJ. Thats the directory .

Answer (score 2):

You also need to create header.php, sidebar.php, footer.php for custom theme.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look like you've built a full theme yourself from what you've posted so perhaps you could add more information to your question.

But, I think you should start by having a read here to check that you're doing it correctly: https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development then post back again if you're still having problems.

Then copy the existing theme to a new folder and start modifying them to get a feel for how they work, then try and build your own.

And then when you're feeling more familiar with how the work, check out the information on child themes here: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/